# Groupby, and convert colum to list for nth recent dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have:

```
     Name    Purchase_Date     Item
  0  Peter    2021-01-01        Car
  1  Peter    2021-02-01       Keys
  2  Peter    2021-03-01  Chocolate
  3  Erika    2021-01-02      Horse
  4  Erika    2021-02-02      Water
  5  Erika    2021-02-02     Laptop
```

I want to get in a column the list of the most recent two(for the sake of the example) purchases (not if Purchase_Date repeats, take both).

So the output would look like:

```
Name.    Purchase_Date.     Items_List
Peter       2021-01-01        [Car]
Peter       2021-02-01       [Keys]
Erika.      2021-01-02        [Horse]
Erika       2021-02-02       [Water, Laptop]
```

As you can see Peter's purchase (chocolate) is not there, its the 3rd and Erika has two items because the date 2021-02-02 repeats.

Tried some group_by and flatten list and all the stuff but not sorting it out.

Code for df:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Peter','Peter','Peter','Erika','Erika','Erika'],
                 'Purchase_Date':['01/01/2021','01/02/2021','01/03/2021','02/01/2021','02/02/2021','02/02/2021'],
                 'Item':['Car','Keys','Chocolate','Horse','Water','Laptop']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your dates `to_datetime` then you can use `groupby` + `rank` to keep up to the first two 'Purchase_Dates' for each person. Then `groupby` + `agg(list)`

```
import pandas as pd

# If not `datetime64[ns]`
df['Purchase_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Purchase_Date'])
df = df.sort_values('Purchase_Date')

df1 = (df[df.groupby('Name')['Purchase_Date'].rank(method='dense').le(2)]
         .groupby(['Name', 'Purchase_Date']).agg(list))
```

---

```
print(df1)
                                Item
Name  Purchase_Date                 
Erika 2021-02-01             [Horse]
      2021-02-02     [Water, Laptop]
Peter 2021-01-01               [Car]
      2021-01-02              [Keys]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
# Convert to datetime
# df['Purchase_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Purchase_Date']

>>> df.groupby(['Name', 'Purchase_Date'], sort=True) \
      .agg({'Item': list}).groupby('Name').head(2)

                                Item
Name  Purchase_Date
Erika 2021-01-02             [Horse]
      2021-02-02     [Water, Laptop]
Peter 2021-01-01               [Car]
      2021-02-01              [Keys]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very valid answer but will give it to the first responder

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` twice to achieve this. I'm assuming your dataframe is already sorted as desired prior to running the below line of code.

```
(data.groupby(['Name', 'Purchase_Date'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg(list)
     .groupby('Name').head(2))
Out[1]: 
    Name Purchase_Date             Item
0  Peter    01/01/2021            [Car]
1  Peter    01/02/2021           [Keys]
3  Erika    02/01/2021          [Horse]
4  Erika    02/02/2021  [Water, Laptop]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a very valid answer but will give it to the first responder